# Yoga 2 pro speakers don't work

Tags: speakers, yoga-2

Like many others, I bought Yoga 2 pro, installed 14.04 and now my speakers don't work.
Audio by earphones work, and HDMI output too.
I checked by Pulse Audio. It seems to work fine and replace between speakers/earphones/HDMI like it should be.

What can I do?